# Problem in calling function parameter as generics dictionary from C# to vb.net

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function written in C# which has one parameter type as  `Dictionary<string , string>`. When i try to call this function in VB.Net it doesn't show the type as `Dictionary<string , string>` it shows as `string`. Below is my function

```
public bool RegisterCustomerAttribute(int CustomerId
                                          , Dictionary<string , string> dictAttribute)
    {
        try
        {

            List<string> keys = new List<string>(dictAttribute.Keys);

            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                CustomerAttribute custattr = new CustomerAttribute();

                custattr.Customer.CustomerID = CustomerId;
                custattr.Key = key;
                custattr.Value = dictAttribute[key];

                customerattrepo.AddCustomerAttribute(custattr);

            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strMsg = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you change the `RegisterCustomerAttribute` method at some point from that old signature to your new one? You have to rebuild the C# project for it to show up in your VB.NET code.

Comment: You are 200% right. Small mistake from my side..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought there might be an overload that only takes a key and value, but you'd see an option for that at least in the intellisense.  So instead, I bet it's looking at old or out of date code — you need to reload the reference to your c# project from your VB project in visual studio.